# TCP Socket using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, tcp

I build an Ethereum wallet app, and I have a python TCP server. I also want TCP client but using swift.

I'm looking for a simple class like we have in python. I am using Swift 5.1

Can someone help me please?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. have you check https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SwiftSocket](https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket) available on github written by **swiftsocket**

it has a class [TCPClient](https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket/blob/master/Sources/TCPClient.swift)

Comment: Outdated package